# SQL query for removing current and future dates?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to filter out all records that have a date in the future AS WELL AS any records in the current month.  I attempted to use this query:

```
...
WHERE (Month(DueDate) < Month(getdate()) AND (Year(DueDate) <= Year(getdate())))
```

The issue is that it doesn't return any results that were previous year but a month that is greater than the current.  ie: Today's date is 9/12/18, it would not return any records that had a month of 10, 11 or 12 regardless of the year.

Comment: If you restate your goal, you will see the logic to use. Essentially you want to ignore rows where DueDate >= [1 day of current month/year]. We can get the current date using getdate. Now how do you change that to the 1st of the current month? You can use dateadd and use DAY as the 1 arg to manipulate it for a given number of days. And we have the Day function to get the current day. So subtract that value (day) from getdate and add 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will filter off any records with a `DueDate` after the first of the current month.

```
WHERE DueDate < DATEADD(MONTH ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

**EDIT**: I had `>`. Should've been `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DueDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);
```

This solution uses `DATEFROMPARTS` function for which you can see more information in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The idea is to get the first of the current month for the current year and select only those rows whose `DueDate` is before the given date and time.

Also, instead of `GETDATE()` [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function you might want to check out `GETUTCDATE()` [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if it's more suited to your needs.

Comment: DATEFROMPARTS was not a valid function in Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Then you probably have a version older then 2012 because it was added then. But good thing someone else provided a solution that works on your instance too.